# Problem installing Spotify on LXDE - E: Unable to locate package spotify-client

Tags: lxde, spotify

I am very new to Linux and am using LXDE (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS) and seem to have a problem installing spotify. I have looked around and couldn't find this specific problem, I hope I am not asking the question while it has already been resolved.

I have the feeling I do everything as it should be done,
using the terminal I add the following to the bottom of the repository:

```
deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free
```

(for instance using sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list or an echo command)

I then run:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4E9CFF4E
```

Than:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

This gives back the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package spotify-client
```

I am really new to Linux so I have no idea if this means my repository is not correct or if the actual package doesn't exist anymore or something else.

Comment: Are you using a 32 or 64 bit system? If you don't know, look it up by executing `file /sbin/init`, there will stand something like `ELF 64-bit LSB...`

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a 32-bit system, you may be out of luck. If you have a look at the [Spotify repository](http://repository.spotify.com/pool/non-free/s/spotify/), you'll see the following files:

```
spotify-client-0.9.17_0.9.17.8.gd06432d.31-1_amd64.deb
spotify-client-gnome-support_0.9.17.1.g9b85d43.7-1_all.deb
spotify-client-qt_0.9.17.1.g9b85d43.7-1_all.deb
spotify-client_0.9.17.1.g9b85d43.7-1_amd64.deb
```

As you see, the package `spotify-client` only exists for the `amd64` architecture, i.e. 64-bit CPUs and systems.

The other two packages are packaged architecture-independently, but they will not provide you with the spotify client. They are transitional packages, which do not provide the Spotify client, as one can see from the package description:

```
Description: Transitional package for spotify-client
 This transitional package is provided for a smooth transition from the previous
 spotify-client-gnome-support package.  It may safely be removed after installation.
```

---

To be able to use the `spotify-client` package and the binaries in it, you need at least a 64-bit kernel, but it may be easier to install the complete system as 64-bit. If your CPU doesn't support 64-bit, you are out of luck...

If you really want to go through the procedure of making your system 64-bit compatible, you'll find various instructions on the internet. I will, however, not provide one here, because I don't want to be responsible if you run in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The installation is indeed 32 bit. I am not sure if the cpu has 64 bit architecture. I'll have a look into that, see if it is even possible to go to 64 bit os.

Answer (score 3):

To anyone having this issue on a 64-bit architecture, remove the existing aptitude source, update then re-install. I'm not sure what went wrong the first time I tried to install, but this worked for me.

1. rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
2. apt-get update

Now re-install using these instructions:
https://www.spotify.com/ca-en/download/linux/

Comment: Happened to me as well. Just tried again and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Lubuntu 15.04 (i386 32 bit) and I installed (emulated) Spotify thanks to `winetricks`. It's a solution for 32-bit users.